# Line separator/Table or Chunk creating big padding in iText

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, itext, padding, spacing

I'm trying to figure out why do I have such big padding on my table when generating a pdf document. Here is an example:

[image]

The table has these properties set:

```
PdfPTable tableSales = new PdfPTable(5);
tableSales.WidthPercentage = 100;
tableSales.SpacingAfter = 0;
tableSales.SpacingBefore = 0;
tableSales.DefaultCell.UseAscender = false;
tableSales.DefaultCell.UseDescender = false;
tableSales.PaddingTop = 0;
```

I've set the UseAscender and UseDescender properties on all individual cells as well so they don't create any padding at all...

The chunks and line separators are defined like this:

```
Chunk linebreak2 = new Chunk(new LineSeparator(1f, 100f, BaseColor.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, -1));
```

I can't get to the bottom of the problem at all... What is creating such big spacing/padding on these red marked areas?

@MethodMan these are the properties I have set already:

```
PdfPTable tableSales = new PdfPTable(5);
                tableSales.WidthPercentage = 100;
                tableSales.SpacingAfter = 0;
                tableSales.SpacingBefore = 0;
                tableSales.DefaultCell.UseAscender = false;
                tableSales.DefaultCell.UseDescender = false;
                tableSales.PaddingTop = 0;

                tableSales.SetWidths(new float[] { 15f, 45f, 10f, 15f, 15f });
```

P.S. This is the complete code for table properties, should I adjut the widths?

Comment: you need to use `tableSales.SetWidths()` method since you have 5 columns you will need to set the widths as new float something like this 
`tableSales.SetWidths(new float[] {60f, 90f, 60f,60f,60f});` mess around with the float settings meaning the numbers ending in `f` adjust or lower put this line above this line `tableSales.WidthPercentage = 100;`

Comment: @MethodMan Okay hold on I'll try with your values for widths

Comment: my values are just an example but you will get the idea once you see the pdf render and you will know which columns to increase or decrease

Comment: @MethodMan err yeah I get you completely. But aren't these values that I've already previously set in alignment perfectly to the margins of the document, since when I set the width of the table to 100% , I can only go up to 100f value when setting these width values in setwidths() method ?

Comment: @MethodMan Actually even when i decrease one column witdth to 1f (meaning it should shrink completely) I still get huge white space above and below the table :/

Comment: I think I found a source of the issue, this chunk with line separator seems to be creating the huge white space

Comment: is it the `100f` part of the line separator ? also looks like you have 2 different line separator sizes that you need to work with / create where is the linebreak1

Comment: @MethodMan Yes  , that's the parameter for setting the percentage of the line separator

Comment: @MethodMan Ye the chunk object and line separator are creating all that white space, just not sure who to set it so it doesn't do that

Comment: if it's for the bottom line or second separator it's smaller in size but by the float value you have it set to a very large number I need to research some old code that I wrote using line separators and see if I can track down how I did it also there is a property that you can look at called `tableSales.SpacingBefore = 15f` for example look at that property as well

Comment: @MethodMan Okay that would be amazing really, ill have a look if chunk or line separator have that property

Comment: @MethodMan I think I found a solution. I simply created an object of LineSeparator type and added it into the docuemnt instead of chunk ... And voila, the white space is gone... I don't know why I added it into the chunk in first place